# Why did my kumquat jam turn dark brown?

Tags: jam

This was my first time making kumquat jam.

I don't know what I did wrong, but the jam looked dark brown while it was still in the pot. Please help.

Comment: Share your recipe for comments on what might be wrong with it, and mention if you skipped or didn't bother with certain steps, as well, in case they were important to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Turned brown in the pot - Probably just oxidation.

Comment: Vitamin C may help .